# php artisan migrate is not making tables in laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-7, laragon

i am trying to migrate my first migration in laravel 7 project i have created database in phpmyadmin. i have Laragon app for localServer, these are my .env code for database connection

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=portfolio-project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

when i do php artisan migrate it tells me that migrations are migrated, but when i go to phpmyadmin for checking tables it says no tables in this database,

Is there any problem with my phpmyadmin?
O any issue in new version 7 of laravel?

because when i added a phpmyadmin to laragon app there was issue with login password of phpmyadmin,
default password was not working and then i think i edit of its files to make no password at login on phpmyadmin after that i just type root as use and login it works, other old version laravel pakgs are working but this new version of laravel is making this issue at php artisan migrate

Comment: If you changed your .env file when application was under `php artisan serve` you need to stop it and run it again to take effect. I'm assuming that you migrated your tables to laravel's default database which is laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that every time you change your .env file you also do the following commands to clear any cache and make sure you are using the latest changes :

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Also make sure that root has no password and you can login to phpmyadmin without one.

Answer (score 0):

First, close the server and the cmd and start it again then run the following command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then run one of these commands:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

or

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

It will drop all tables and recreate them again with the new migrations.

Hope it helps :)